# Difference between ASP.Net Applications and ASP.Net Apps vSomething Performance Counter Sets

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2016, perfmon

On Microsoft Windows Server 2016 (and probably earlier versions) I see several Performance Monitor Counter sets/categories that have similar names and similar counters:

```
\ASP.NET Applications(*)\*
\ASP.NET Apps v2.0.50727(*)\*
\ASP.NET Apps v4.0.30319(*)\*
```

What is the relationship between these counter sets?  Will the results in `\ASP.NET Applications(*)\*` be some sort of aggregation of the other two?  Is usage of each based on the .Net CLR version of the app pool?  Has anyone seen an official explanation?  Google has not helped me.

thanks!

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Microsoft Support:

> `\ASP.NET Applications(*)\*` - These counters aggregate information from all ASP.NET applications on a Web server computer.
>
> `\ASP.NET Apps v2.0.50727(*)\*` - These counters provide the information from all ASP.NET 2.0 based applications on a Web server computer.
>
> `\ASP.NET Apps v4.0.30319(*)\*` - These counters provide the information from all ASP.NET 4.0 based applications on a Web server computer.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Martin